# CS0246 Type or namespace "Newtonsoft" not found

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, namespaces, json.net

after clean installation of Unity3D (2018.1.1f1) it post-installed VS 2017 (15.7.3).
I begun a cs script, and want to debug an object "print_r"-style, so I installed Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2 by th nuGet Package-Manager.
If i call "Get-Package" in the pakage-console, it shows to me

```
Newtonsoft.Json                     {11.0.2}                                 Assembly-CSharp
```

Unfortunately it still pushes me errors when i try to compile:

```
Schweregrad Code    Beschreibung    Projekt Datei   Zeile   Unterdrückungszustand
```

Fehler  CS0246  Der Typ- oder Namespacename "Newtonsoft" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis). Assembly-CSharp C:\Users\bubu\Documents\Therapiefilm\Assets\test.cs 4   Aktiv
It means the Namespace "Newtonsoft" wasnt found or an Assembly-Link is missing.

But I dont know what the error actually is. ;-(

Any hint is welcome!
Regards 
Rene´
ps: my script-source:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class test : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    private static void Dump(object o)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try RMB on project and Restore NuGet Packages.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use one of the prepared Newtonsoft.Json forks that have changed it to be compatible with Unity3D. They are much easier to use than the NuGet package, and unlike the official NuGet package that will fail at runtime when building to AOT targets such as Android, iOS, WebGL, etc., they all have support for this. Here are the top three:

- [jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity), Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.1-12.0.3, available via the Unity Package Manager (UPM) that's built-in Unity 2018.1 and upwards.
- [SaladLab/Json.Net.Unity](https://github.com/SaladLab/Json.Net.Unity3D), Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1-9.0.1, available via `.unitypackage` and UniGet
- [ParentElement's JSON .NET for Unity](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347), Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.3, available via the Unity Assets Store

The variant by jilleJr is the only active fork at time of writing. The others has stopped development.

Installation instructions taken from [jilleJr's wiki](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity/wiki/Installation-via-UPM)

> Open /Packages/manifest.json, add scope for jillejr, then add the package in the list of dependencies.
>
> À la:
>
> ```
> {
>   "scopedRegistries": [
>     {
>       "name": "Packages from jillejr",
>       "url": "https://npm.cloudsmith.io/jillejr/newtonsoft-json-for-unity/",
>       "scopes": ["jillejr"]
>     }
>   ],
>   "dependencies": {
>     "jillejr.newtonsoft.json-for-unity": "12.0.201",
>
>     // ...
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> <sub>`// ...` signals the rest of the packages you have in the manifest.json, such as all the `"com.unity.*"` dependencies</sub>

Answer (score -1):

I've found the easiest way to incorporate Newtonsoft.Json, is to go to the [NuGet site](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/), and manually download the package. Then, unzip all of the files in to a "Plugins" folder under your assets directory, i.e. Assets/Plugins/Json.NET.

You should also be setting your Player Scripting Runtime Version to .NET 4.x. I also set my API compatibility to .NET Standard 2.0. Though while recommended, it's not required.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I reinstalled the NuGet Package and added the Newtonsoft.Json refernece manually (since it didn't set the refernece automatically for some reason) and now in VS my script knows the class and doesn't show any errors anymore! The unity editor however, still shows the same error message. Do you have any other ideas please?

Comment: The Newtonsfot.Json files (four of them) are under Assets/Plugins/Json.NET? In the Editor are you able to select the DLL to view the DLL's information? Is there a warning that the DLL has been removed in the console? Is your project Player Settings set to .NET 4.x?

Comment: YAY! Changing the Player Settings to .net4.x did the trick! Thank you very much!

Comment: @ReneMunsch, if you could mark that as the answer, so I can build my reputation, I'd appreciate that. Thanks : )